# typescript optional parameter check before using

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters, tsc

Does tsc give error for code like this with some tscconfig rules?

```
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName?: string) {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

I think if there is no code to check lastName is not undefined, there must be tsc compiling error.
How can I get tsc to give error on compililation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating with a variable that contains `undefined` is weird, but not forbidden by JS, so it won't throw a TS error.

But usually it's not what you want, and indicates a problem. The [restrict-plus-operands](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/restrict-plus-operands/) TSLint [or ESLint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/restrict-plus-operands.md) rule forbids this:

[image]

Comment: question is not about only "concatenation". Question is using optional parameter without checking for it is undefined or not

Comment: How are you using it other than with `+`? Attempts to use it that require it not to be undefined are already not permitted by TS. For example, `console.log(lastName.slice(0, 3));` is not permitted, since it might be undefined.

Comment: hmm it seems you are right. plus operator makes coercing so it accepts undefined values like console.log(lastName). otherwise it is work as I expected; Thank you for answer.